# Java convert StringBuilder into CharBuffer

Tags: java, type-conversion, stringbuilder

I need to send some `StringBuilder sb` content using a CharBuffer
I was hopping for something like `CharBuffer.wrap( sb)` but cannot find any elegant way

Before settling for brute force, **Is there a neat way to transform StringBuilder into CharBuffer?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CharBuffer` has an `append(CharSequence)` method. And a `StringBuilder` is a `CharSequence`.

So

```
charBuffer.append(stringBuilder)
```

UPDATE:
Better yet, since `CharBuffer.wrap` also allows for a `CharSequence`, in fact your original idea was ok

```
CharBuffer.wrap(stringBuilder);
```

should work.

Comment: My Bad for trusting SO more than my own instincts!